# C#: Inserting HTML content -> MS Word: images & tables autoscaling (i.e losing width & height style attributes)

Tags: c#, html, ms-word

I am using C# to generate reports in MS Word. I have a predefined .docx template and I use mail merge fields which are then updated by my app.

I retrieve small sections of HTML content from a database and insert them into the appropriate points in the MS Word document as follows:

1. I retrieve the HTML content
2. I wrap the content with tags:

   `<HTML>
       <TITLE></TITLE>
       <BODY>
       ... content ...
       </BODY>
    </HTML>`
3. Save html content into a temporary file
4. Use the Word._Application.Selection.InsertFile() method to insert the HTML file

Example of converted HTML code:

```
<html>
<title></title>
<body>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 700px; ">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-top: 0cm; padding-right: 5.4pt; padding-bottom: 0cm; padding-left: 5.4pt; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 150px; ">
            <img alt="see attached image: screenshot-3.jpg" src="XXXXX/screenshot-3.jpg" style="width: 60px; height: 84px; " />
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br />
</body>
</html>
```

The above system works, but I find that tables and images are 'auto-scaled' by MS Word, with images being rendered with their original dimensions as opposed to the embedded style="width, height" attributes.

My HTML is rendered 100% in a browser, but not in MS Word.

Any ideas on how to get my scaling right would be most appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience HTML may be the easiest way of getting rich text into a Word document, but it's also prone to get formatting wrong and you don't have control over the finer details.

Have you tried using the `width` and `height` attributes for the `img` element? Another option might be to try using RTF (which is on par with Word, feature-wise).

Comment: Thanks Joey - setting the **width** and **height** attributes causes MS Word to scale them properly.